# jquery multiple slider

Tags: jquery, slider

I have the following code for a basic Jquery Slider, but this code only executes a single div with the class: "slide-wrapper", but I need to run 2 or more sliders at a time ... this is my complete code:

HTML:

```
<!-- SLIDE 1 -->
<div class="slide-wrapper">
    <div class="slide">

        <a href="#"><img src="images/tmp/adv_left_sup.jpg" width="600" height="100" /></a>

    </div>
    <div class="slide initial-hide">

        <a href="#"><img src="images/tmp/adv_left_sup_2.jpg" width="600" height="100" /></a>

    </div>
    <div class="slide initial-hide">

        <a href="#"><img src="images/tmp/adv_left_sup_3.jpg" width="600" height="100" /></a>

    </div>
</div>

<!-- SLIDE 2 -->
<div class="slide-wrapper">
    <div class="slide">

        <a href="#"><img src="images/tmp/adv_left_sup.jpg" width="600" height="100" /></a>

    </div>
    <div class="slide initial-hide">

        <a href="#"><img src="images/tmp/adv_left_sup_2.jpg" width="600" height="100" /></a>

    </div>
    <div class="slide initial-hide">

        <a href="#"><img src="images/tmp/adv_left_sup_3.jpg" width="600" height="100" /></a>

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slide-wrapper { position: relative; height: 100px; }
.slide-wrapper div.slide { position: absolute; }
.slide-wrapper .initial-hide { display: none; }
```

JS:

```
var currentPosition = 0;
var totalSlides = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {  
    // slides
    totalSlides = $('.slide-wrapper .slide').length;
    setTimeout('transition()', 3000);

});

    transition = function() {
        currentPosition++;
        lastPosition = currentPosition - 1;
        if (currentPosition == totalSlides)
            currentPosition = 0;

        if (lastPosition < 0)
            lastPosition = totalSlides - 1;

        $('.slide-wrapper .slide:eq(' + lastPosition + ')').fadeOut('slow');
        $('.slide-wrapper .slide:eq(' + currentPosition + ')').fadeIn('slow');

        setTimeout('transition()', 3000);
    }
```

I hope your help, thanks
p.d. sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 0):

Mmm i don understand totaly (my english to is ungly)...

Are you using a [jquery-ui slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/)?

check that, you can do sliders and multi-sliders.

You have a 2 sliders with at some classname "slide-wrapper", how convert this in sliders?

```
$('slide-wrapper').slider({...});
```

you can have a lot of element with classname slider-wrapper, and some one have an id,ex;

```
<div class="slide-wrapper" id="slider1">
```

And from Jquery:

```
$('#slider1').slider({...});
```

Comment: Not using another plugin, jquery only, how the same function applied to each ID, without repeating the function?

Comment: realy i recomended use JQuery-ui